# ask for  a simple bijective proof  about oriented increasing binary trees

Tags: co.combinatorics

Give a bijective proof-----the number of oriented increasing binary trees on the vertex set
$\lbrace 1,2,\cdots,n\rbrace$ is the Eulerian number $E_n$(the number of alternating permutations in 
$\mathfrak{S}_n$).
alternating permutation is downup permutation.

Comment: I'm afraid the question -- as asked -- doesn't make sense to me. Could you explain what the words mean?

Comment: Incomprehensible AND probably homework. Voting to close.

Comment: Igor -- I disagree. I think it is just incomprehensible. I've also voted to close; to be reversed if the author edits the question making it clear what they have in mind (and avoiding the imperative mood if possible).

Answer (score 1):

I searched for the meanings of the words using Google, and I suspect that this document answers your question:

www.stat.wisc.edu/~callan/notes/donaghey_bij/donaghey_bij.pdf